# How do I mark a disk as OK (Asus/Intel Software RAID)

Tags: windows, motherboard, raid

I have an Asus P8Z77V_PRO mobo using Intel RAID (Windows 7 x64).

A drive has an error, but after examining it with SMART tools, I'm satisfied the drive is fine.  Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to tell the mobo's RAID that "all is well, please rebuild the array".

1. There appear to be no desktop tools...at least none that I could find on the Asus site for this mobo.  On my previous box, I'd use Intel's Matrix Storage Manager but that doesn't seem to be installed and I can't find anything on the Asus site or the CD that came with my mobo.
2. The BIOS doesn't seem to offer the option.  I'm considering making it non-RAID, then marking it as a replacement - but I can't find any docs that explain if this will work.  The BIOS is quite confusing.

I tried unplugging the "bad" drive, booting, then plugging it back in and booting but the BIOS apparently caches the serial number or something.  I was hoping it'd just recognize it as a new disk.

Do I really need to delete the RAID array and recreate it?  Kind of defeats the point of RAID :-)

Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Comment: In win7 64 the software would be Intels RST (rapid storage technology) I cant be sure, but the same software talks to many chips, get the OS right down to the 64bit part, and i would give it a try. Right from intel. and there is a "matrix" software https://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=eng&ProductFamily=Software+Products&ProductLine=Chipset+Software&ProductProduct=Intel%c2%ae+Rapid+Storage+Technology+(Intel%c2%ae+RST)  ?

Comment: I was able to find the software you need to download on the asus website.  I suggest you take another look.  I suggest you install the `Intel(R) AHCI/RAID Driver for Windows 7/8/8.1 32bit & 64bit` from the ASUS website.

Comment: The driver isn't what I need - I have that.  I need whatever GUI controls it.  Or is that GUI bundled with the driver?

Comment: Thanks very much, Psycogeek - installing the Matrix software let me mark it as normal and rebuild.